# Nosetests failing when no file is specified

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, nose

I am testing some python code and when I`m running nosetests with the file specified, Everything is good, but when I want to run everything in the folder, some of the tests (most) fail.

I am using mock, unittest and nose with python 2.7

Thank you

for example:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: mock('fake/path')
Not called
```

on this test

```
def test_vm_exists(self):
    fake_path = 'fake/path'
    os.path.exists = mock.MagicMock()
    os.path.exists.return_value = True

    response = self._VixConnection.vm_exists(fake_path)

    os.path.exists.assert_called_with(fake_path)
    self.assertEqual(response, True)
```

this is the repo:
https://github.com/trobert2/nova-vix-driver/tree/unittests/vix/tests

Sorry if it wasn't descriptive enough.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you show some code? what fails, which exception,... Please improve your question.

Comment: I did an edit. Thank you for your input

Comment: Thank you so much! Patching solves everything. When I used MagicMock I thought it will only work in the scope of the test. I was wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually mocking `os.path.exists` as used by the actual code. Try the following:

```
@mock.patch('os.path.exists')
def test_vm_exists(self, mock_exists):
    mock_exists.return_value = True
    fake_path = 'fake/path'

    response = self._VixConnection.vm_exists(fake_path)

    mock_exists.assert_called_with(fake_path)
    self.assertEqual(response, True)
```